# React state update input data

Tags: reactjs

I have developed react application, with router which has 2 routes. In one Page I am displaying the value, in the other page I have one form which has two input fields(Email and Phone) and one button. I have Onchange event for each input field. as soon as I do changes in input field and without clicking on update button, if I go back to the first page the data is updating without submitting. But after refresh it will get back to original value.
Can you please help me out, How to avoid the updating data.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format'
import {
  useForm,
  Controller,
  ErrorMessage,
} from 'react-hook-form/dist/react-hook-form.ie11'
import isValidEmailAddress from '../utility/isValidEmailAddress'
import Messages from './Messages'
import Button from './Button'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function EditContactInformation({
  changeContactInfoSmall,
  contactInfo,
  updateContactInfo,
}) {
  const { handleSubmit, register, control, errors } = useForm()
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(() => changeContactInfo(contactInfo))}>
      <h3>Edit contact information</h3>
      <Messages results={contactInfo} />
      <div className="edit-contact-information__form-col">
        <div className="form-group form-group--email">
          <label htmlFor="email">Preferred email address</label>
          <input
            name="email"
            id="email"
            type="text"
            ref={register({
              required: 'Please enter an email address',
              validate: (value) =>
                isValidEmailAddress(value) ||
                'Please enter a valid email address',
            })}
            onChange={(e) => {
                updateContactInfo('email', e.currentTarget.value)
                return e.currentTarget.value
            }}
            defaultValue={contactInfo.get('email')}
          />
          <ErrorMessage
            errors={errors}
            name="email"
            as={<div className="form-errors" />}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group form-group--phone">
          <label htmlFor="phone">Preferred phone</label>
          <Controller
            as={<NumberFormat id="phone" format="(###) ###-####" mask="_" />}
            name="phone"
            rules={{
              required: 'Please enter a phone number',
              minLength: {
                value: 10,
                message: 'Please enter a valid phone number',
              },
            }}
            onChangeName="onValueChange"
            onChange={([{ value }]) => {
              updateContactInfo('phone', value)
              return value
            }}
            control={control}
            defaultValue={contactInfo.get('phone')}
          />
          <ErrorMessage
            errors={errors}
            name="phone"
            as={<div className="form-errors" />}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="updateAll"
            data-testid="update-all-button"
            onChange={(e) => {
              updateContactInfo('updateAll', e.currentTarget.checked)
            }}
            ref={register()}
          />{' '}
          Update my contact information for all properties
        </label>
      </div>
      <Button
        className="button--primary"
        arrow
        type="submit"
        isLoading={contactInfo.get('submitting')}
      >
        Update contact
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}

EditContactInformation.propTypes = {
  changeContactInfo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  contactInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  updateContactInfo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use session storage for this situation. React states are deleted when the page is refreshed due to its nature. You should keep the information you want to keep session storage.

Answer (score 0):

States in react are non persistent, meaning that data stored in state is purged when the site is refreshed or navigated out of. So, if you want to hold on to your data, depending on your need, you can either use cookies or your browser's local storage to persist.

[react-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-persist) is a great library that you can use to achieve this using localStorage.